# how to handle nearly concurrent events on a camunda event gateway

Tags: camunda, bpmn, camunda-modeler

I am calling an external system that is supposed to send two events A and B sequentially. But they are so fast that they land up almost at the same time.
Considering the "FLOW A" (blued), the event based gateway waits for Event A and then activity "do something" is executed before another event based gateway accepts Event B or Event C.
The Super Fast System responds with either events A and B or A and C almost at the same time (millisecond difference). This results in the engine discarding the events B or C. What should be the optimum design?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Implement a retry + delay mechanism on the message broker / event bus or sending system, which kicks in if the message cannot be correlated.